# How to hide "HOT META POSTS" on the sidebar

Tags: support, per-site-meta, community-bulletin

How do I hide **just** the "HOT META POSTS". I don't intend to engage much in the moderation of Stack Exchange sites, so most of the content is irrelevant to me, how do I hide it?

I looked into just adding a user style sheet filter based on the `id` or `class` of that element, but then the whole `community-bulletin` box gets hidden, which might hide important site level messages/broadcasts.

Specially since the DOM structure of the "HOT META POSTS" is not different than the "FEATURED ON META" section, i.e. both use same classes and no `id` is provided.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your idea is good, but you'll need a [general sibling combinator](https://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/#article-header-id-2) for the CSS to work as intended. Sadly, we need to [select based on the content](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1520429/4751173) as well, because there are sites where/times when there are no Featured On Meta posts (e.g [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) right now) so we can't rely on it not being the first title. That means a user stylesheet won't work, but we can resort to a userscript:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Hide Hot Meta Posts
// @match       *://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @match       *://*.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match       *://*.superuser.com/*
// @match       *://*.serverfault.com/*
// @match       *://*.askubuntu.com/*
// @match       *://*.stackapps.com/*
// @match       *://*.mathoverflow.net/*
// @exclude     *://chat.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude     *://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude     *://chat.stackoverflow.com/*
// @exclude     *://blog.stackoverflow.com/*
// @exclude     *://*.area51.stackexchange.com/*
// @grant none
// ==/UserScript==

(function () {
  $("div.bulletin-title:contains(Hot Meta Posts), div.bulletin-title:contains(Hot Meta Posts) ~ hr, div.bulletin-title:contains(Hot Meta Posts) ~ div").hide();
})();
```

Comment: `:contains` is not yet added to css I guess.

Comment: Yeah, this is not valid CSS. That pseudo-selector only exists in jQuery. It has never been supported by an official CSS standard and afaik has never been implemented by any browser.