# Allow to hide "Featured on Meta" in the user settings page

Tags: feature-request

I know I could simply not interact with it but I cannot not see what is most of the time irrelevant content to me. I am not interested in the "Hot Network Questions" list and I am glad that I can turn it off.

**Could we have a similar option to hide "Featured on Meta"?**

---

Please note that this isn't the same question as [How to hide "HOT META POSTS" on the sidebar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311461/how-to-hide-hot-meta-posts-on-the-sidebar) - I am not asking how to do this via a user script but to have it as an option in the user settings page.

---

*Addendum I*

*Don't get me wrong; meta sites are useful but I know where to find them when I need support or want to make suggestions.*

*Addendum II*

*Given the ongoing developments with SE & its community, I hope this feature request isn't seen as disrespectful to anyone involved. It certainly isn't my intention!*

Comment: Fortunately, it's in a rather easy place to block via adblock, ublock, or any other content blocking or userscript tool.

Comment: @random I would like to respectfully challenge the closing of this question - I'm not asking how to hide it _myself_ but whether it would make sense to have this as an option _similar_ to the one for hiding the "Hot Network Questions" in the sidebar. The closing of the question is unfair IMHO.

Comment: I agree with this. There really needs to be a UI option. Preferably a little "cross" in the top-right corner of the widget to make it really easy (and you can click the minimised box to expand it later). I actually just asked the exact same question over at meta.stackoverflow https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/393054/how-do-i-hide-the-featured-on-meta-widget-in-the-sidebar At times when meta becomes a mud-slinging contest, it would be nice to be able to hide it for a little while.

Comment: This isn't a dupe. This is a feature request, the other is asking how to do this on one's own.

Comment: Workaround: zoom in so the right panel is not visible (though "Linked" and "Related" are gone too)

Comment: I really just want to close it and be rid of it, it's too distracting and hasn't once helped me do my job. I'd like a checkbox in the user preferences, not a script or some other work-around.

Comment: Another option that might work for the community bulletin (which includes "Featured on Meta" and "Hot Meta Posts"), and potentially "Hot Network Questions" and other "sidebars" as well (like the linked/related questions), might be to make them collapsible by clicking on the corresponding header of that section. Obviously, slight interface changes would need to be made to make it clear that collapsing works this way; maybe a -/+ sign or a rotating dropdown arrow (pointing down when uncollapsed, and pointing to the right when collapsed) could be added next to the section header.